# Migrating project from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, migration

I'm migrating my solutions from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0. I open the solution file in VS 2010 and follow migration wizard.

While building the solution and comparing the changes with the server copy (since solution is under source control VSTS), I surprisingly found that

1) the public classes were changed to 'internal'  and

2) the 'public static' properties were changed to 'internal static'

It gave me problem because the output assembly is referred in other projects.

Can someone explain why does it happen? Also, are there any other such changes taking place behind the scene? Or Am I doing something wrong ?

(Note: I have ReSharper 5.1 installed but I think it has no place in this case.)

Comment: I have never experienced what you describe when migrating a project.  I'm using Resharper 5.0.

Comment: @ProfK : Even I was surprised to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper may have given the suggestion to make methods static for those methods which are not using any instance variable or method within it. This is what I have observed.

Similarly, if the methods are not accessed from any other project/assembly, it may give you suggestion to make them internal.